# Validating GamceCenter user credentials in the backend

Tags: ios, game-center

I am building a backend for ios apps, that support **login in different networks**.

**Once** the user **login** in to the network the client tells the news to **the backend**, and this could **offer a list of worlds** that the user might play, or even delete old worlds.

One way to steal another person's world is by saying that you are his social network id.

To solve that **with facebook**, we force the client to send us the **fb_token**, a token provided from facebook to the client, that we use in the backend to ask facebook if that specific user is the one that he told us to be.

**If apple doesn't provide a way to validate this I understand that if an iOS app wants to use game center, *it is directly forcing the app developer to also use iCloud* because apple can validate the user credentials.**

Did apple provide any way to validate user credentials?

Comment: And yes, the communication with the iOS app is encrypted and signed, but all the security in all the systems can be bypass.

Answer (score -1):

The client on iOS can retrieve info about the **currently logged in** player in GameCenter, which has nothing to do with iCloud.
If you want to use iCloud to authenticate, you might have a different player than the one you wanted.

I think the solution is for the client to retrieve the player info in GameCenter, and send it to your server in an encrypted fashion (say HTTPS), including a timestamp and possibly other dynamic information. This way you'll know that the user info is being sent from the client app itself and there is no man-in-the-middle. That's really the issue that you are struggling with: how to ensure that client-server communication is secure.

Comment: As said in the comment, the communication is signed with a password transmitted over https the first time the device register into the system.

The client can just hook a debuger after getting the game_center_id from api and before communicate with the backend and use a different game_center from a player with for example, better world or progress. From now on, the hacker can play in the other users world, and on the backend there is no way to check that client is not legit. With facebook we ask the facebook servers to see if that user is the one that pretend to be.

Comment: So you assume the hacker can disassemble the protocol used, and figure out the passwords used, and inject a different GCid in the stream. That's a tall order. Unless your game communication is in the clear, which is wrong. Use https for everything and encrypt the CGid with a timestamp and other stuff if you like, and the hacker will need to completely disassemble the program to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Yes, and what happened before was that one user do that, release an exe file allowing all the users to do that in a simple way. Even people selling that app in game forums.

The problem is that is not accessing others people data. Is becoming others people.

Comment: Let me get this straight. Assume device logs in with GCid==A and password=P. Then when game starts, it uses GCid==B for all communications? Your problem is in your networking. Make sure your server returns a session token T that will be used for all further communications. In your backend, you link T to A for the session. The client will never be able to switch to B.

Comment: The problem is that a user should be able to play on different devices. And following apple guidelines, several game center users can play in the same device.